# Iterating over Object of Objects to create Array

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

I have an `Object` containing more `objects` that I want to iterate over. The structure is like this:

[image: Objects in Objects]

Eventually, I want to create an `array` where the `key` of the **parent object** points to the `value` in the **child object's title column**, so I can post later to some PHP script, i.e, I want:

```
BusinessJustification => 'titleValue'
Contract => 'titleValue'
...
```

But I am really struggling to actually loop through the array.

I have tried the following two methods, and while I can loop over the parent object, I seem to be struggling to get access to the values in the child, they just show as the index position, or `undefined` respectively.

```
for (var fields in this.postData) {
    for (var columns in fields){
        console.log(columns['title']);
    }
}

for (var fields in this.postData) {
    for (var columns in fields){
        console.log(Object.entries(columns['title']));
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am really scratching my head, and have tried a few things online.

Comment: in order to help you,Please provide the object

Comment: I tried to in the picture I included. Is that not enough?

Comment: It will be enough when you'll be able to copy/paste text from/to a picture.

Comment: What do you want to do with those values? Because `columns['title'];` only accesses the value in the property, it doesn't ***do*** anything with it.

Comment: Sorry that's actually I typo on my part, I was using console.log on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I eventually want to create an `array` where the `key` of the parent object points to the `value` in the child object's title column.

You can't generate an `array` with those properties in `Javascript` like you do in `PHP`: *An array in `PHP` is actually an ordered `map`. A `map` is a type that associates `values` to `keys`*. But you can create a `Javascript` [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics), or a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). However, I believe the first options is the one you need if you are going to send data to some server-side `PHP` script.

I believe you are searching for this:

```js
const postData = {
    BusinessJustification: {blur: true, title: "business-title", valid: true},
    Contact: {blur: true, title: "contact-title", valid: true},
    Department: {blur: true, title: "department-title", valid: true},
}

let newObj = {};

for (const field in postData)
{
  newObj[field] = postData[field].title;
}

console.log(newObj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Perfect that was just what I was looking for. I wasn't expecting it to be that easy!